# secure communication between PHP and C++

Tags: php, c++, security, soap

I have an application written in C++, and I'd like to send requests and get data securily from it by PHP. I was thinking about using SOAP but I'd like to ask you if there are any other possibilites. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) in itself is not secure - just a set of rules to use XML.

You need [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

Comment: Ok I'll look at it. Do you know some good tutorial or article to start with?

Comment: @DropDropped - Not off the top of my head. A search with Google should throw something up. Also the link above to SSL will have links to other sites that may be of value.